# Start date and end date iterating using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a excel VBA code, where i would like to iterate the start end and end date adding + 2.

**Scenario and assumption in sheet1 as shown below**

cell reference **I1**= 13-Jul-2018

Input Table
from A1 till C17 the cells value are with column header

```
stocks  start end   end date
dummy1      
dummy2      
dummy3      
dummy4      
dummy5      
dummy6
```

The code logic required

Initially **I1** as the start date i,e **13-Jul-18** of the first row

In the Same row, for end date should add +2 , that will be **15-Jul-18**

In the next row, **start date** will be the previous row **end date(15-Jul-18)** by adding **+1** that will be 16-Jul-18

And in the Same row, **End date** will be the added +2 of the same row **start date(16-Jul-18)** that will be **18-Jul-18**

The same logic flows to the next occurring row till the stock column is blank

if any change in the start end of that row changes , the changes should start from the current row to the next rows with same above logic

Example the output is

```
stocks  start end   end date
dummy1  13-Jul-18   15-Jul-18
dummy2  16-Jul-18   18-Jul-18
dummy3  19-Jul-18   21-Jul-18
dummy4  22-Jul-18   24-Jul-18
dummy5  25-Jul-18   27-Jul-18
dummy6  28-Jul-18   30-Jul-18
```

Code I have written below,Need your help!!!

```
Sub zigZag()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Integer
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws.Activate
currentValue = Range("I1").Value
ws.Range("A2").Activate 
Do
 If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Do
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = currentValue
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = currentValue + 2
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) + 1
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2) = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1) + 2
 ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Activate
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Think you are looking for `DateAdd()` you could say `EndDate = DateAdd("d", 2, StartDate)` And the next start date would be `StartDate = DateAdd("d", 1, EndDate)`. Check [DateAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcxe65wz(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Nesset,let me kickstart using this functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**module code 1 ' initiate code base on range("i1")**

```
Sub zigZag()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    Dim currentValue As Date
    Dim vDB As Variant, rngDB As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        currentValue = .Range("I1").Value
        r = .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngDB = .Range("b2", "c" & r)
        vDB = rngDB 'get Array from range(2 dimension)
        vDB(1, 1) = currentValue
        vDB(1, 2) = vDB(1, 1) + 2
        For i = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)
            vDB(i, 1) = vDB(i - 1, 1) + 3
            vDB(i, 2) = vDB(i, 1) + 2
        Next i
    End With
    rngDB = vDB
End Sub
```

**'Module code 2 ~~> The code to call in the sheet event code**

```
Sub zigZagRng(rng As Range)
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    Dim vDB As Variant, rngDB As Range
    Dim currentValue As Date

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        currentValue = rng.Value
        r = .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngDB = .Range(rng, "c" & r)
        vDB = rngDB 'get Array from range(2 dimension)
        vDB(1, 1) = currentValue
        vDB(1, 2) = vDB(1, 1) + 2
        For i = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)
            vDB(i, 1) = vDB(i - 1, 1) + 3
            vDB(i, 2) = vDB(i, 1) + 2
        Next i
    End With
    rngDB = vDB
End Sub
```

**Sheet event code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Row > 1 And Target.Column = 2 Then
        zigZagRng Target
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Dy.Lee for the code , its working on the first iterations. but if any value changes in the start date column, the next occurring rows is not changing.

Comment: Thanks for the code. its working  now. Could you suggest me if there many sheets(like 30 to 50) in the same workbook . are there any performance lags of this due worksheet_change event ???

Comment: Could you give input on this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47098850/holiday-date-must-be-excluded

Comment: @Rod, sorry I don't know efficient method about your problem.

Answer (score 1):

**The 1st part**, the code below will run the first time, and modify all the dates according to the date in cell "I1".

***Regular Module Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub zigZag()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim CurrentStartDate As Date

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    CurrentStartDate = .Range("I1").Value

    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row in column "A"

    ' first row logic (with ref. of value in cell "I1")
    .Range("B2").Value = CurrentStartDate
    .Range("C2").Value = DateAdd("d", 2, CurrentStartDate)

    ' loop through the rest of the rows
    For i = 3 To LastRow
        .Range("B" & i).Value = DateAdd("d", 1, .Range("C" & i - 1).Value) ' current start equals previous end + 1
        .Range("C" & i).Value = DateAdd("d", 2, .Range("B" & i).Value) ' current end equals current start + 2
    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

**The 2nd part**, you need to add to your `Sheet1` worksheet module, to `Worksheet_Change` events, so whenever someone changes a value in column B (`start end`), then all dates from that row and below will be modifed as well.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long

' if a 'start end' was modifed, in column "B"
If Target.Column = 2 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("C" & Target.Row).Value = DateAdd("d", 2, Target.Value) ' add 2 days to current row end date

    For i = Target.Row + 1 To LastRow
        Range("B" & i).Value = DateAdd("d", 1, Range("C" & i - 1).Value) ' current start equals previous end + 1
        Range("C" & i).Value = DateAdd("d", 2, Range("B" & i).Value) ' current end equals current start + 2
    Next i

End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Shai Rado for the code. its working as expected. suggest me if there many sheets(like 30 to 50)  in the sameworkbook . are there any performance lags of this worksheet_change event ? I share you another challenges after deploying this later...

Comment: @Rod  so you ended up giving the "Answer" to the other solution ?

Comment: both solutions are working good for me but i can't mark "Answer" for both.

Comment: @Rod then choose the one you decided to use.

Comment: i have two workbook. I am using both the solutions  :-)

Comment: @ Shai Rado  Could you give input on this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47098850/holiday-date-must-be-excluded?noredirect=1#comment81148834_47098850